# Вывод дочерних комментариев в шаблоне родителя

Tags: php

Использую известный метод, когда данные из Mysql сортируются по **PID**, **ID**. В итоге получаем выходной массив вида:

```
$arr = array(
     array('id'=>1, 'pid'=>0, 'name'=>'Comment 1'),
     array('id'=>8, 'pid'=>0, 'name'=>'Comment 2'),
     array('id'=>9, 'pid'=>0, 'name'=>'Comment 3'),
     array('id'=>10, 'pid'=>0, 'name'=>'Comment 4'),
     array('id'=>11, 'pid'=>0, 'name'=>'Comment 5'),
      array('id'=>2, 'pid'=>1, 'name'=>'Comment 1.1'),
      array('id'=>3, 'pid'=>1, 'name'=>'Comment 1.2'),
      array('id'=>6, 'pid'=>1, 'name'=>'Comment 1.3'),
       array('id'=>4, 'pid'=>2, 'name'=>'Comment 1.1.1'),
       array('id'=>5, 'pid'=>2, 'name'=>'Comment 1.1.2'),
       array('id'=>7, 'pid'=>2, 'name'=>'Comment 1.1.3'),
     array('id'=>12, 'pid'=>8, 'name'=>'Comment 2.1'),
      array('id'=>17, 'pid'=>8, 'name'=>'Comment 2.2'),
      array('id'=>14, 'pid'=>9, 'name'=>'Comment 3.1'),
      array('id'=>13, 'pid'=>12, 'name'=>'Comment 2.1.1'),
       array('id'=>16, 'pid'=>13, 'name'=>'Comment 2.1.1.1'),
       array('id'=>15, 'pid'=>14, 'name'=>'Comment 3.1.1'),
     );
```

**Меняем структуру массива:**

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($arr); $i < $c; $i++)
     {
       $new_arr[$arr[$i]['pid']][] = $arr[$i];
     }
```

**Рекурсивная функция вывода комментариев:**

```
  function my_sort($data, $parent = 0, $level = 0)
     {
       $arr = $data[$parent];

       for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
       {
         $commentParent.='<div>'.$arr[$i]['name'].'<div class="dotter">Здесь под каждый комментарием - все дочерние комменты, если есть</div></div>';
           if(isset($data[$arr[$i]['id']])) my_sort($data, $arr[$i]['id'], 20);
       }
     }
```

Вся сложность в том, что не получается вывести в одном потоке **ВСЕ** дочерние комментарии **class="dotter"** в "родительских" блоках.

**Пробовал делать так:**

В цикле делал проверку на то, является ли дочерний комментарий к его родителю:

```
if ($parent > 0){
  $dotter.= 'Comment 1.2';
}
```

Если да, то складировал отдельно в `$dotter` все дочерние комменты. Таким образом, сейчас `parent` и `dotter` комментарии в отдельных шаблонах. Остается распределить  `$dotter` по всем соответствующим `$commentParent`.

**Смысл моей идеи был таков:**

Отделить **parent** и **children** комментарии в шаблоны (строку). В комментариях, где `parent = 0` -родители, выставить в строке некий строчный идентификатор `%id_parent%`,
для того, чтобы с помощью сделать замену строк:

```
str_replace("%id_parent_%", $dotter, $commentParent);
```

Т-е, зная **PID** дочернего комментария, мы вставляем его шаблон `$dotter` в позицию `%id_parent_%` шаблона `$commentParent`.

Кто сможет помочь, будет очень крут, потому как сам пока решить не могу...

Comment: Решение придумал, кому будет интерес - выложу полный гавно-код

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.